# Nested for loop python equation

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to python and coding and I have a problem where I need to use nested for loops to solve an equation where `i^3 + j^3 + k^3 = N`. Where `N` is 50 to 53 and `i`, `j`, `k` have a range of -800 to 800.

I do not understand how to use a nested for loop for this. Every example I have seen of for loops they are used for creating matrices or arrays.

The code I have tried output a very large amounts of falses.

```
for i in range (-800,801):
    for j in range (-800,801):
        for k in range(-800,801):
            for N in range (50,54):
                print(i**3+j**3+k**3==N,end=" ")
            print()
```

Am I on the right track here? I got a large amount of false outputs so does that mean it ran it and is giving me a every possible outcome? I just need to know the numbers that exists that make the statement true

Comment: Why would I need an if statement? I do not see examples of nested loops with if statements

Comment: You do if you want to easily sift out the falses.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is check if
i^3+j^3+k^3==N
and only print i, j and k if the statement is true.

You can do that by adding:

```
for i in range(-800, 801):
    for j in range(-800, 801):
        for k in range(-800, 801):
            for N in range(50, 54):
                if i**3+j**3+k**3 == N:
                    print(i, j, k, N)
```

output:

```
-796 602 659 51
-796 659 602 51
```

Answer (score 1):

The nested loops are not your problem, they are already correct.

You need to print the values of `i`, `j`, `k`, and `N` only **if** they satisfy the equation. For this purpose of conditional execution of code, Python (as many other programming languages) has `if` statements.

You learn about them in the official [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) or in any good beginners book about programming in Python, like [Think Python](https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2006.html#sec58) or [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter2/).

In your case, you can apply an `if` statement like this:

Instead of unconditionally printing

```
print(i**3+j**3+k**3==N,end=" ")
```

use

```
if i**3+j**3+k**3==N:
    print(i, j, k, N)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of times the equation is correct:

```
count = 0
for i in range(-800,801):
    for j in range(-800,801):
        for k in range(-800,801):
            for N in range(50,54):
                if (i**3 + j**3 + k**3) == N:
                    count+= 1
print(count)
```